# TimeZoneInfo - AdjustmentRule error on .net core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a piece of code that allows me to get the current date/time (local).

It will be run on Azure.

I'm getting universal time and converting it to local UK time (taking into consideration for BST - British Summer Time).

While migrating from a .NET 4.6.1/Core project to .NET Core 1.1 I'm now faced with a error.

> The type name 'AdjustmentRule' does not exist in the type
>   'TimeZoneInfo'
>
> 'TimeZoneInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetAdjustmentRules'
>   and no extension method 'GetAdjustmentRules' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'TimeZoneInfo' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Using .NET Core 1.1 only - how can I resolve this?**

```
public static DateTime GetLocalDateTimeNow()
{
    DateTime localDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

    // Get the venue time zone info
    TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    TimeSpan timeDiffUtcClient = tz.BaseUtcOffset;
    localDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Add(timeDiffUtcClient);

    if (tz.SupportsDaylightSavingTime && tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(localDate))
    {
        TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[] rules = tz.GetAdjustmentRules();
        foreach (var adjustmentRule in rules)
        {
            if (adjustmentRule.DateStart <= localDate && adjustmentRule.DateEnd >= localDate)
            {
                localDate = localDate.Add(adjustmentRule.DaylightDelta);
            }
        }
    }

    DateTimeOffset utcDate = localDate.ToUniversalTime();

    return localDate;
}
```

I don't mind replacing the implementation as long as it takes into account BST and runs on .net core 1.1 (without 4.6.1).

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do any of this yourself - just ask `TimeZoneInfo` to do the conversion. That's what it's there for!

```
// Only need to do this once...
private static readonly TimeZoneInfo londonZone =
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");

public static DateTime GetUkDateTimeNow() =>
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, londonZone);
```

A few notes:

- I've renamed `GetLocalDateTimeNow()` to `GetUkDateTimeNow()` to make it clear that it's always dealing with the UK time zone, not the time zone local to a particular user or computer
- On Unix, you'd need to ask for `"Europe/London"` instead of `"GMT Standard Time"`
- To make it independent of any of that - and indeed of the system local time zone data - you could use my [Noda Time project](http://nodatime.org) which I'd like to think will give you generally cleaner code instead.

Almost no-one needs to deal with `AdjustmentRule` in their code. I do in Noda Time, because I need to be able to represent `TimeZoneInfo` zones as Noda Time `DateTimeZone` objects, but that's pretty unusual. If you ever *do* need to use them, they're far more complicated than you might expect, and there have been several occurrences of bugs in the .NET implementation; I'm currently (as in, today) fighting bugs in the Mono implementation instead...

As an aside, I would *strongly* urge you not to use `DateTime.Now` anywhere. Always use `DateTime.UtcNow`, and then convert into the system local time zone if you really, really need to.

Comment: If it's not too hard to describe, can you say *why* we shouldn't use `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: @RufusL: In theory, it could be lossy - UTC to local date/time conversions can lose data, because multiple UTC times can map to the same local time. It's also inefficient - the system clock is effectively in UTC, so you're currently mapping from UTC to local and back again.

Comment: @RufusL: In reality, the conversion "remembers" in its `Kind` backing-field whether the original value was in DST or not. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/ for details. But better not to do it anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and helpful